# Can Geokit work with AR in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, geokit

I have a Sinatra app with AR bundled. Geokit-wise, I have the requirement to keep the logic in certain models provided by the acts_as_mappable mixin. Thing is, this mixin is part of geokit-rails3, not geokit. And that gems depends from rails 3. Isn't there a way to decouple the parts in order to make a reliable geokit-activerecord implementation instead of coupling it tightly to the framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *geokit-rails3* gem depends on the *rails* gem you can do nothing about it. The only option left is to rewrite the *geokit-rails3* gem or extract the parts needed from it into your project.

I also suggest looking into the *geocoder* gem, since it seems to be better maintained at the moment (*geokit* is practically dead) and it comes with an ActiveRecord integration in the main gem itself...